# Visual C++ always builds succeeded but no output is created. Problem with the highlight asm extension VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, assembly

I'm learning ASM, I install MASM32 and VS2019 Community (C++ Desktop Environment). 
I copy a sample online

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none
include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib

.data
MsgBoxCaption  db "Iczelion Tutorial No.2",0
MsgBoxText       db "Win32 Assembly is Great!",0

.code
start:
invoke MessageBox, NULL, addr MsgBoxText, addr MsgBoxCaption, MB_OK
invoke ExitProcess, NULL
end start
```

It works well until I installed highlight asm extension ASM DUDE. Then the project always builds succeeded but without executable.

The output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Project1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Visual Studio already includes MASM, the 32 bit version is ML.EXE, the 64 bit version is ML64.EXE. There may be a default setup on a fresh install, but I generally set properties for each .asm source file: excluded from build (no or blank), custom build tool: command line `ml /c /Zi /Fo$(OutDir)\x.obj x.asm` (/Zi is not needed for release build) output `$(OutDir)\x.obj`

Comment: If you go to `Build Dependencies` and select `Build Customizations`, is Masm selected?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd - it could also be the properties for the .asm file have excluded from build set to yes (the default for .asm files depending on the initial installation).

Comment: @rcgldr thank you. I have solved my problem. I miss configuring .asm file. Find a help at  http://www.asmirvine.com/gettingStartedVS2015/index.htm  Step 6 - Creating a 32-Bit Project From Scratch.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I do set the Build Customizations. Thank for your reminder